# Почему при проверке массива на наличие только четных чисел выдает true, даже если там нечетные числа?

Tags: javascript

почему при проверке в массиве на четные числа выдает true, даже если там нечетные?

```js
function num(arr) {
   for (let i of arr) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
         return true
      }
   }

   return false
}

console.log(num([1, 4, 6]))
```

Comment: for пробегает по массиву - "1" не соответствует условию, но команд никаких нет, "забивает" и идёт к следующему элементу. "4" - соответствует, возвращает true.

Comment: function num(arr) {
   for (let i of arr) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
         return true
      } if ( i % 2 != 0) {
       return false
      }
   }

   
}

console.log(num([1, 4, 6]))                   Добавит  еще один if будет уместно?

Comment: @Dresosr Неуместно. Вы *не можете* выйти из функции/цикла на первом встреченном четном.

Comment: function num(arr) {
   for (let i of arr) {
      if (i % 2 != 0) {
         return false
      }
   }

   return true
}

console.log(num([1, 4, 6]))  а так?

Comment: @Dresosr Зачем Вы переписываете в комментарии код из моего ответа?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сказать, что в массиве **все** числа четные, надо проверить **все** элементы массива до первого нечетного.

```js
function num(arr) {
  for (let i of arr) {
    if (i % 2) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(num([1, 4, 6]));
console.log(num([128, 4, 6]));
```

```js
function num(arr) {
  return arr.every(i => i % 2 == 0);
}

console.log(num([1, 4, 6]));
console.log(num([128, 4, 6]));
```

Comment: как я понял моя ошибка в том, что он возвращает true, если попадается первое четное число, даже если дальше нечетное, но я не понимаю смысл этой строчки if (i % 2) {return false; } Получается, что задается условие, если число делится на два, то тогда выдается false и не понимаю почему именно так?

Comment: а если сформулировать так - Если при переборе массива попадается первое число, которое не делится на 2, то сразу выдается false, а если при полном прохождении массива все числа делятся на 2, выдается true. Верно?

Comment: @Dresosr `if (i % 2)` => `if (i % 2 != 0)`